# My Comments Not Posting on Youtube with Safari (macOS)

Tags: macos, safari, youtube, google, websites

My comments are not posting on Youtube while I use Safari (11.1.2) on macOS? I only have one extension which is the Hoversee extension, nothing else, I'm almost certain that's not why YouTube is acting up and not letting me post comments all of a sudden. I was able to post comments on Youtube on Safari on macOS just a few days ago, now I can't. Does anyone know what might be the problem?

I also noticed the notifications pane won't load my notifications either.

Comment: Can you post comments in Chrome or Firefox?

Comment: Yes I can. I am running the latest version of FireFox on macOS. I wonder if this issue is happening because I have an older version of Safari (11.1.2).

Comment: It's quite possible that it's due to an older version of Safari.  As for your updates, it's a different question altogether and should be posted as a new one and not appended to this one.  COVID-19 has nothing to do with either problem and is off topic here.

Comment: Well, if these problems are happening as a result of less staff at Youtube, I would assume that it might be because of the response to COVID-19 which would not be off topic as far as I can tell since that could explain why this is happening, which is why I mentioned it. Regardless, I shouldn't have jumped to conclusions, but it might be an explanation. I also have spoken to some people on the subreddit r/YouTube and some people are currently experiencing the same issue with Safari and other browsers.